# Execution Queue

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, batch-processing

I have a need to process 100 pieces of information through an external program.  These processes can be intensive, so I need to limit it to processing 8 at a time.  Essentially, I'd like to launch 8 processes, and as each one completes, launch the next one.

I have attempted to use TPL in System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow with the below code, but all 100 launch, not just 8 at a time.

```
// This file has the command line parameters to launch the external process
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();
var block = new ActionBlock<string>(async job => await RunJob(job), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 });
foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            block.SendAsync(line);

        }

static async Task RunJob(string parms)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("PARMS: {0}", parms);
            Process proc = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            start.FileName = @"C:\program.exe";
            string parameters = String.Format(parms.ToString());
            start.Arguments = parameters;
            start.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.StartInfo = start;
            proc.Start();
        }
```

What have I missed?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process starts immediately, but you don't wait until process ends. Use `proc.WaitForExit();`

```
static async Task RunJob(string parms)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("PARMS: {0}", parms);
    Process proc = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    start.FileName = @"C:\program.exe";
    string parameters = String.Format(parms.ToString());
    start.Arguments = parameters;
    start.UseShellExecute = true;
    proc.StartInfo = start;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't MaxDegreeOfParallelism be set to 8 as well to achieve 8 concurrent processes?

Comment: Do you know how I can make the code wait for the completion of all processes and then continue with further processing past this?

Comment: @StephenGray block.Completion.Wait(); ??

Comment: a sample for actionblock https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1.complete?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Dataflow_ActionBlock_1_Complete